# why there is a left over java process even after the closure of the spark context

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I wrote a small application in python that accepts requests and executes pyspark jobs in worker processes. Things are working fine but even after closing the spark context the java process that spanned when starting the spark context still exits. I checked the cluster and the resources are also released properly after the closure of the context. Also the worker is processing subsequent requests with out any issues .

```
10542 pts/3    Sl+    0:00          \_ Worker - 1 
12960 pts/3    Sl+    0:22          |   \_ /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_77//bin/java - hdp.version=3.0.0.0-1634 -cp /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/spark2//conf/:/usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/spark2/jars/*:/usr
```

There are 2 questions

1. Why the sparkcontext.stop not killing the java process on the master node
2. My cluster is kerberos integrated cluster . Worker submits the job with keytab and principal populated in the spark context. If the Worker is not processing any jobs for a decent amount of time , the next job is errored out with exception:

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Delegation
>   Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication.

When I restart the application, things are fine again. I am suspecting because of expired token left in the java process I am facing this issue. Is there a better way to handle this scenario .

I strongly believe if the java process is not left over i wouldn't face the 2nd issue.

Any suggestions/pointer will be a great help .

Additional Info : The jobs are submitted as "yarn" and deploy mode is "client".

Comment: PySpark relies on `py4j` gateway, which stays alive between sessions. I don't know how to force it to stop _explicitly_, just google on that topic...

Comment: Read about "long-running Spark jobs" (streaming in particular) and `--principal` / `--keytab` command-line options (or the underlying Spark properties) about credentials auto-renewal by Driver